# Multiple elements with popup module

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have an example of modal popup, where the scrolling is blocked in the back, but it is enabled in the pop-up itself.

Take a look at my example: [Example here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pxGIa)

The problem i have is, that i would like to have a grid of images in the website:

Take a look what kind of grid i mean: [enter link description here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bhkgs)

After a user would click on one of those images, he would get an popup with different images. But off course the popup images would be different for each photo the users click, it's a portfolio of different project.

PROBLEM: after i want to combine those two examples, the jQuery popup stops working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you keep an structure like this in HTML :

```
<a href="#" class="info" id="overlay1">...</a>
<div class="overlay">Content for overlay 1</div>
<a href="#" class="info" id="overlay2">...</a>
<div class="overlay">Content for overlay 2</div>
```

Take in care with the `id` because that need to be unique and can't be multiple in the document.

Then you need to change your functions to be handle by the classnames and not the id like this:

```
$(".info").click(function(event) {
  var ne = $(this).next('div.overlay');
  event.preventDefault();
  ne.fadeToggle(500);
  return false;
  $(".close").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ne.fadeToggle(500);
  });
});
```

Check this **[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ymxHd)**

Comment: One problem came up.. when i close the pop-up the scroll on the page jumps to top. I want to be at that point where i open it, because the website will definitely be longer, and at the portfolio will be more at the end not top. So users should always scroll back down.

Comment: @DeanDeey I understand what you want is tricky i guess if u can make a new question can be interesting to solve. Right now I don't have time. PD . Link me your new question I want to know how to solve that :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to change the overflow from `visible` to `auto` in your close function.